# Freeware which can encrypt a whole directory by command line and output one single file

Tags: encryption

This one doesn't seem to be able to ouput one single file 
https://superuser.com/questions/67721/how-to-encrypt-a-whole-directory-with-axcrypt-by-command-line-like-with-windows-c

Any other windows freeware which can do so by command line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), command line version (7za.exe).

Answer (score 3):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) has a command-line interface. You can create an encrypted archive.

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) also has a command-line interface, though I'm not sure if it's capable of archiving everything into a single file.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use tar to dump a directory structure to a file, then encrypt that single file with the tool of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

7-Zip is a good option.

In fact I liked it enough to write a batch file script that's 7-Zip-based (free / open source). Since it's all command-line, it's easy to schedule for creating unattended encrypted archives:

> **[Ziparcy](http://wittman.org/ziparcy/)** is a WINNT shell script that can be scheduled to create/update an encrypted zip/archive of your files (and directory structure).